# When using Theme.MaterialComponents the color for + and - in ElegantNumberButton is changing

Tags: android, android-layout, themes

In order to use Chip and ChipGroup, I set the Application style extends Theme.MaterialComponents
 in manifests.xml, then  the color of "+" and "-" in ElegantNumberButton is changing  [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvj2V.jpg)  [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4VGC.jpg)

This is my style (after using MaterialComponents):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>-->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>


        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```

and this is the button

```
<com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:id="@+id/number_button"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        app:backGroundColor="#F42A42"
                        app:finalNumber="20"
                        app:initialNumber="1"
                        app:textSize="8sp"
                        />
```

what can I do?

Comment: "What can I do?" You could start by giving us some context and share the XML and code for the issue.

Comment: @Francesc thank you for your advice ... I already shared Xml of the button and my style code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your library is not meant to work yet with Material styles. Use the `bridge` version of the theme,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">
```